# Android "A folder failed to be renamed or moved" (fixes tried, no success)

Tags: android, sdk

Here is how my story goes.  At first, I installed the Android SDK in the default directory it selected, which was Program File (x86) (which I thought the default was supposed to be app data?!)  After SUCCESSFULLY pulling the APIs I quickly realized the mistake I had made, due to spaces being in the name, so I then uninstalled it and re-installed it in my D drive under a folder called development.

That all went fine, but when I tried to pull the SDK, I received the "A folder failed to be renamed or moved" message.  I then tried disabling my anti-virus (more on that later), closing all other windows, and even ending windows explorer, but nothing changed.

To disable my antivirus, I used it's control panel (Avast BTW) to turn off the shields.  What I really wanted to do was end the process, but, and here is the big but, Access Denied!  I even ran taskmgr.exe as admin, but no success.  Can anyone explain why that is?  Anyways, after getting fed up with it all, I just booted into safemode with networking, and all is well for now, but I really would hate doing this every time I need to update the SDK, so any suggestions on how to fix this would be a great help, especially how to end my antivirus process so I can see if that's the problem.

EDIT: And I also did all that while running the Android SDK manager as administrator from the folder it is installed in.

Comment: Are you encountering this problem when you upgrade or install something new from the sdk manager?Is the symptom that sdk manager would download the package normally but an alert dialog would pop up when the manager tries to install it ? If so, I have run into such problem and sloved it.

Comment: This happens when I try to install something new.  Everything downloads, but then the dialog box pops up when it tries to install it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I assume that the problem happens because the upgrade program wants to upgrade itself directly while it is running. My solution is that every time before you want to install something new, make a copy of **`\<sdk dir>\tools`** dir in the **`\<sdk dir>\`**  path, and then, upgrade or install something by excecuting **android.bat** in the **`copied tools`** folder. This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

try rename "platform-tools" folder as "_platform-tools" and create a new folder as name "platform-tools".

that's work for me!

Answer (score 1):

Having eclipse open sometimes causes this.

Open the Android SDK Manager then close eclipse before you press the "install packages" button and it should be fine.